# How do i create a Job in SSRS?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have created a report and subscriptions but when I go to SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio and connect to Report Server I do not see anything under Jobs folder. When I right-click I do not see an option to create a Job. How do I make a job so that it shows under this folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can check

1. Is SQLAgent currently turned on?
2. Is SQL Agent set to auto-start?
3. Under what permissions (i.e. user account or proxy account) is SQLAgent set to run?
4. What type of subscription did you create? scheduled? data-driven? (the latter is an enterprise-edition only feature)
5. What delivery method for the subscriptions? to a folder? via email?  If to a folder, does the SQLAgent account have the appropriate permissions to read/write on that shared folder?  If via email, have you configured the SMTP settings in SSRS configuration tool?
6. I am assuming that SSRS is installed in native (not SharePoint integrated mode) - is this correct?  There are different set of troubleshooting steps if the latter

For completeness, [here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156307.aspx) an MSDN reference (step-by-step) on how to create a subscription.  Also I assume that your user account has the appropriate permissions to create other types (that is, non-SSRS subscription jobs) of new jobs on your SQL Server instance via SSMS.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I have created an subscription and i get an email, that is working fine. The SQL Server Agent is turned on and set to auto start. The thing i do not understand is what goes in the Jobs folder when i connect to the Report Server instance inside the Management Studio. I have 3 folders there Jobs, Security and Shared Schedules. I cannot create a Job by right-clicking on the Job folder. what is supposed to show up under that folder?